# Windows Server 2008 Restarts and Freezes

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a Dual Intel 5420 (8 cores) running with 16GB of ram, 2 x 1.5TB drives in Software RAID 1 running Windows Server 2008.

I have been having major problems with the server rebooting unexpectedly lately, and freezing on the login screen and just a black frozen screen.

The server originally had Linux with Xen HVM installed and 3 vps units, one of the units had 5 cores and most of the ram running windows. It wasnt enough so we opted for the whole dedi just for windows. Seeing as it was running 3 vps units without problems it shouldn't have a single problem running windows.

It ran after the initial install for about and hour then rebooted without warning. We re-installed and asked the DC to run a hardware test. They found nothing wrong. After the install it lasted another hour and again. We opted to have both HDD's replaced. They did and we re-installed again. Again, this time 2 hours and it rebooted.

So we asked for another model MB as we thought that maybe it wasn't compatible with windows. Same thing, rebooted. This after a new MB and Proc.

So i thought maybe power supply, its happened before. So the DC changed out the PSU, PDU and Cable. This time it lasted about 4 hours and again, rebooted.

So i asked for a completely new unit and re-install. They did this.

This time it seemed to work, it lasted me an initial install of 48 hours. Then we ran a load testing software for another 48 hours to make sure. It lasted all of this no problems.

We then turned it over to the .net software installers. It lasted 2 hours then rebooted. We thought maybe it was a fluke, so we left it.

It has lasted since Nov. without rebooting once. On Thu. it just froze on the login screen out of the blue. We rebooted it manually then about 6 hours later it froze again on a black screen. At this point it has lasted all weekend.

Since it's all new hardware and has lasted all this time i am pretty positive it is no longer hardware. That and i had the DC run a full gammit of hardware tests on Thu. taking 5 hours, including full ram module tests.

It runs at about 14gb of ram usage out of 16gb 90% of the time due to running software in RDP sessions.

The server is used for remote RDP login to run school software, the software is a bit of a pig at 90Mb starting per open process, growing from there. We have about 30 teachers and staff at each school and two locations. Today i counted 30 logged in RDP sessions active using the software.

Of course the server runs it's SQL server as well, along with IIS, Apache, and Filezilla ftp. Apache is a simple php api, nothing more and few users.

I am not an experienced windows tech but my thought is it's no longer hardware but now an overloaded server with software and too many users.

Where can i go from here to test some more? Could the software RAID be causing this? If so can i safely test by turning it off?

What else could it be and what am I missing?

Comment: Have you looked at the Windows event logs? Have you looked at any available hardware logs? Have you disabled auto restart in the recovery options to see if it's a BSOD?

Comment: The event logs unfortunately only show something to the effect of "restarted after unexpected shutdown". Where would i find hardware logs and could you tell me how to disable the auto-restart? Never heard of it. Im willing to try anything at this point.

Comment: Auto-restart would be in the BIOS.

Comment: Control Panel|System|Advanced System Settings|Advanced tab|Startup and Recovery|Settings|Automatically restart checkbox - uncheck that box

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of the auto reboot upon power failure setting.

Comment: Check all the drivers, not just RAID.  If you have not installed the manufacturer's drivers, try them.   If you have, try uninstalling them and using Microsoft drivers (or an earlier release from the manufacturer).  This certainly smells like a driver-related BSOD.

Comment: I have noticed a BUNCH of event logs stating remote printer errors lately, I mean a bunch. I can get a screenshot of one if that will help. Could that cause the problem?

Comment: @joeqwerty Thanks, auto-restart is already unchecked it seems.